# How to do multiple regular expressions, each time refining the results?

Tags: javascript, regex, greasemonkey

**Why can't I output my regex to a variable, and then run regex on it a second time?**

I'm writing a greasemonkey javascript that **grabs some raw data, runs some regex on it, then runs some more regex on it to refine the results**:

```
// I tried this on :: http://stackoverflow.com/
var tagsraw = (document.getElementById("subheader").innerHTML);
alert(tagsraw);
```

Getting the raw data (above code) works

```
var trimone = tagsraw.match(/title\W\W\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g);
alert(trimone);
```

running regex once works (above code); but running (code below) doesn't??

```
var trimtwo = trimone.match(/\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g);
alert(trimtwo);
```

Can some advise me as to what is wrong with my code/approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the first match works, is because innerHTML returns a string.

However the match returns an array, thus treat it as one:

```
for (var i=0; i<trimone.length; i++)
{
    var trimtwo = trimone[i].match(/\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g);
    alert(trimtwo);
}
```

Edit:

Try this code instead though, I think this is a bit closer to what you want to achieve:

```
var trimone = tagsraw.match(/title\s*=\s*".*"/g);
alert(trimone);

for (var i=0; i<trimone.length; i++)
{
    alert(trimone[i]);
}
```

Comment: I don't believe this is the desired result.  What he really needs is the matched string and that's exactly what the exec function from the Regexp object is for.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var str = "<title> foo bar baz quux blah</title>",
    re = [
        /title\W\W\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g,
        /\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g
    ],
    tmp = [str];
for (var i=0, n=re.length; i<n; ++i) {
    tmp = tmp.map(function(val) {
        return val.match(re[i])[0];
    });
}
alert(tmp);
```

Comment: thanks gumbo, i don't understand how this works, in relation to my example.

Answer (score 0):

.match should be returning an array, not a string.

Comment: so you are saying alert(trimone); will display ok... But when I want to do some more regex, I can't because it is an array?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that match() returns an array and there is no built-in function to perform a regular expression on an array.

So instead you should be able to do this with the [exec function from the Regexp object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_exec_regexp.asp).  It will return the matched string.  You can grab the matched string from the first regexp and use it for the second.

So it'd be something like this:

```
var patt1 = new Regexp(/title\W\W\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g);
var trimone = patt1.exec(tagsraw);

if (trimone != null) // might be null if no match is found
{
  alert(trimone);

  var patt2 = new Regexp(/\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g);
  var trimtwo = patt2.exec(trimone);
  alert(trimtwo);
}
```

Note that exec returns null if no match is found so be sure to handle that in your code  like I do above.

Comment: I can't get this to work on stackoverflow.com
// try this on :: http://stackoverflow.com/

var tagsraw = (document.getElementById("subheader").innerHTML);
//alert(tagsraw);

var patt1 = new Regexp(/title\W\W\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g);
var trimone = patt1.exec(tagsraw);

if (trimone != null) // might be null if no match is found
{
//  alert(trimone);

  var patt2 = new Regexp(/\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g);
  var trimtwo = patt2.exec(trimone);
  alert(trimtwo);

Comment: Lets say that tagsraw is my raw data, then trimone trims it down to 3 blocks of data, then trimtwo should be able to pull out a title & text, or pull out a title & a post number, for example

Comment: Lets say that tagsraw is my raw data, then trimone trims it down to 3 blocks of data, then trimtwo should be able to pull out a title & text, or pull out a title & a post number, for each block of data.
I hope that explains what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is better suited to using `.exec`.  You could even chain the two if you don't care about the intermediate result:

```
/\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g.exec(/title\W\W\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+\s\w+/g.exec(tagsraw));
```

Comment: ok thanks Brandon, I like this approach, it does allow me to keep refining over and over, which is how I would like to work.  However the first .exec only returns one find even though /g global is on.  I was trying to take the raw data, trim it down to smaller block of data, over and over, each time cleaning away more rubbish, and finally ending up with say a few pairs of items, for example: a Title1 & Summary1, Title2 & Summary2, etc...  I'll keep trying with this